# Graphics Card problems on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have got a strange problem, my video card is a **Nvidia gtx 970** right now using **Nouveau display driver**, if I use proprietary driver by Nvidia everything works ***until*** the pc goes in the sleep state, when I "wake" it up it tells me there is **no network available** (I only use wired connection), but this doesn't happen if I use open source drivers... 
The only problem with open source drivers is that all the videos on the web flicker which didn't happen while using proprietary.
Is there a way to fix all this mess?
Thank you

I ran the `inix -F`and this is what I got:

> neil@Balthasar:~$ inxi -F 
>   **System**:    Host: Balthasar Kernel: 4.2.0-34-generic x86_64 (64 bit)  
>              Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 Distro: Ubuntu 15.10 wily 
>   **Machine**:   Mobo: Gigabyte model: Z97X-Gaming 7 v: x.x 
>              Bios: American Megatrends v: F6 date: 05/30/2014 
>   **CPU**:       Quad core Intel Core i7-4790K (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB 
>              clock speeds: max: 4400 MHz 1: 4379 MHz 2: 4116 MHz 3: 4388 MHz 
>              4: 4340 MHz 5: 4400 MHz 6: 4400 MHz 7: 4376 MHz 8: 4400 MHz 
>   **Graphics**:  Card-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller 
>              Card-2: NVIDIA GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] 
>              Display Server: X.Org 1.17.2 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
>  FAILED: intel,nouveau
>              Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz 
>              GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits) 
>              GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2 
>   **Audio**:     Card-1 NVIDIA GM204 High Definition Audio Controller 
>              driver: snd_hda_intel 
>              Card-2 Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio 
>  Controller
>              driver: snd_hda_intel
>              Card-3 Intel 9 Series Family HD Audio Controller
>              driver: snd_hda_intel
>              Card-4 Logitech Webcam C270
>  driver: USB Audio
>              Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.2.0-34-generic
>   **Network**:   Card: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
>              driver: alx
>              IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full
>              mac:
>   Drives:    HDD Total Size: 280.1GB (8.8% used)
>              ID-1: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_840 size: 120.0GB
>              ID-2: /dev/sdb model: Hitachi_HTS54161 size: 160.0GB
>   Partition: ID-1: / size: 46G used: 5.0G (12%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb5
>              ID-2: /home size: 74G used: 3.9G (6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb6
>              ID-3: /tmp size: 13G used: 33M (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb7
>              ID-4: swap-1 size: 16.00GB used: 0.01GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sdb1
>   RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present 
>   Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C
>              Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
>   Info:      Processes: 227 Uptime: 2 days Memory: 2406.6/7829.7MB
>              Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.16

Comment: Not really sure what the video driver would have to with the networking not working... Could you add what kernel and specific distro version, and the output of `inxi -G` and `inxi -n`, or maybe even `inxi -F` so we can see what hardware you are talking about? If your distro gives an error, try installing inxi with `sudo apt-get install inxi` first. Thanks.

Comment: I did as you told me and I posted the result in the question

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't see any red flags that jump out at me, sorry, but I am not familiar with the specifics of some of your hardware.

Comment: Thank you anyway, I hope there is someone who can help me sooner or later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you trying latest version of drivers and xfwm.

Fisrtsly xfwm4. After release of 4.12.3 main developer has pushed a lot of commits. Now xfwm4 relies upon glx backend, which fix tearing and may fix problems with your gpu. To do this follow these instructions:

1. Install dependencies for building xfwm4 `sudo apt-get build-dep xfwm4`
2. Install extra dependencies and git `sudo apt-get install git libepoxy0 libepoxy-dev`
3. Clone form git `git clone http://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4`
4. `cd xfwm4`
5. `./autogen.sh`
6. `make`
7. `sudo make install` ( If you would like to install a package run `sudo checkinstall`)

Now run `xfwm4 --replace` and test whether everything is OK.

The second thing you may try to do is to wait until release of kernel 4.6 which will enable HW acceleration on [latest Nvidia Maxwell](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GTX900-Easy-Nouveau-Setup&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20Phoronix%20(Phoronix)) generation

And the last - try installing latest beta Nvidia driver version 364. If you were using before driver with version lower than 361, try latest stable driver from this ppa `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`